# vb.net browser control does not open all links or popups to a new window

Tags: vb.net, axwebbrowser

So there is this site https://webbrowsertools.com/popup-blocker/.  I am using this to test for popups.

On system default browser like Edge, Chrome and Firefox, when you click those test buttons for popups, popups are shown.

However, I created this vb.net web browser app using webbrowser and axwebbrowser control but only Method 1 of Window.Open type, methods 1 to 5 of Target type, method 1 of Form type and Method 1 & 2 of Misc type.

Why is it that not all of test popup types in that web site, run on webbrowser and axwebbrowser ?  The only code I currently run on my project is below:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Dim URL As String
        URL = "https://webbrowsertools.com/popup-blocker/" 

        'for webbrowser control if I use webbrowser
        WebBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True
        WebBrowser1.Navigate(URL)

        'for axwebbrowser control if I use axwebbrowser
        axWebBrowser1.Silent= True
        axWebBrowser1.Navigate(URL)
    End Sub
```

I am not catching the new window here yet to check for popups if they will appear.